# Java - Why cannot type parameters be in a catch clause?

Tags: java, generics, try-catch

I know that generic types cannot extends Throwable and I understand that this doesn't make sense because type erasure (exceptions are thrown only at runtime) and other subtle things.

However Java allows a type parameter to be bounded by Throwable in fact the following code is legal

```
class MyClass<T extends Throwable> { /*body of the class */ }
```

What is illegal is the use of the `T` parameter in a catch clause

```
try { //do something that throws exception //  }
catch(T e) /* ILLEGAL!!! DOESN'T COMPILE */ {}
```

The only reason that I can understand about this constraint is that the type parameter, because erasure, is replaced by its bounding type, in this case `Throwable`.
But type parameters could be bounded also by more than one bounding type so I could have this situation

```
class MyClass<T extends Object & Throwable> [*]
```

in such case `T` is replaced after erasure by `Object` and I know that an `Object` (that is not of type `Throwable`) variable cannot be inside a catch clause.

Let me know if this is the reason about this Java constraint. Thanks.

EDIT: 
[*] As davidxxx make me notice, this class declaration doesn't compile because `Throwable` is not an inteface.

Comment: `class MyClass<T extends Object & Throwable>` will not compile. You can only specify interfaces after the first type. So it should be rather  `MyClass<T extends Throwable & OneInterface>`. But even with it, you would have the same compiler restriction on the `catch` statement.

Comment: You are right. Throwable is not an interface. The "-able" suffix misled me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no way for the runtime to check if the type of a caught exception matches `T` because it does not know what `T` is.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26768399/7366707) for some additional information - type parameters are kept on methods and classes, but not variables.

The point of a `catch` block is that you can handle exceptions by providing specific behavior to the exception type. This is also why you can supply multiple `catch` blocks for a single `try`. Without the specific exception type it would not be possible to execute the correct `catch` block.

Also, what do you expect the code to do if you run it with a raw type? The way you propose, `T` would be replaced with `Throwable` and the `catch` block would now catch *all* exceptions instead of only those of a certain type.

Additionally, the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20) specifies `CatchType` as:

```
CatchType:
    ClassType
    ClassType | CatchType
```

which does not include `TypeArgument`.

If you *really* want to do this, you can catch `Throwable` and check the type using `instanceof` or using its `Class`:

```
try {
    doSomethingDangerous();
} catch (Throwable t) {
    if (t instanceof IOException) {
        handleIoException(t);
    } else if (...) {
        ...
    } else {
        handleOther(t);
    }
}
```

Note: [Catching `Throwable` or `Exception` is usually considered *very* bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083248/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-catch-throwable).

Edit: [here's what it looks like in C# for possible reference](http://ideone.com/N9tXAs).

Comment: So, if I have `MyClass<RuntimeException> c=...` and if `T` was legal in `catch` clause, at runtime `catch {}` block would have handled also exceptions of different type such as `NullPointerException` or `Exception`, etc. Is it right?

Comment: @Vin Theoretically, a NPE _would_ be handled (but an `Exception` wouldn't because `RuntimeException` is actually a subclass of `Exception`.) For example, [it is possible to do this in C#](http://ideone.com/N9tXAs) if you want an example of what it would look like.

Comment: Ok. I don't understand about that `RuntimeException` is a subclass of `Exception`. Replacing `T` with `Throwable`, it doesn't matter what the actual type parameter is, catch block handle every type of `Throwable`. Theoretically speaking.

Comment: @Vin In your comment, the type parameter was `RuntimeException`, not `Throwable`. If you are referring to what would happen if the type parameter was _erased_, then yes it would likely be erased to `Throwable`. However, using type parameters in `catch` blocks is not (and probably will not be supported for a long time, if ever) supported, possibly _because_ of erasure, so this is just pure speculation. I provided a possible workaround if you need this functionality. If this answer helped, you can [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I refer to the bounding type that is `Throwable`, and after erasure `T` is replaced by `Throwable`. Sorry if I explain it bad.

Comment: Answer accepted, but I would add another reason why Java made this illegal. Suppose `catch(T e)` is legal, in case of multi catch block this would have created problems.

Comment: Side note, you can't use type parameter in `if (e instanceof T)` so you should try a cast and catch the `ClassCastException`: `try { T t = (T)e; handleT(t); } catch (ClassCastException ex) { handleOther(e); /* e, not ex */ }`. If you *really* want to.